# query in rails3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I got an issue in rails3.1, in the rails console

```
a=User.find_by_name 'castiel'
a.name #output: castiel

a=User.where "name like 'c%'"
a.name #output: User
#both query got the same thing,but why the second one output 'User'
```

I used a new feature in rails3.1 which is about authentication, you know the one that introduced in railscast episode [authentication-in-rails3.1](http://media.railscasts.com/assets/episodes/videos/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1.m4v),maybe it's got something to do with this,just thought it might be good to let u know the circumstances here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `find_by_name` and `where` are **not** returning the same thing.  `find_by_name` will find the first User that matches your query.  `where` will return a collection of Users that match your query.

In your first example, the result is a single User object, so `a.name` gives you `"castiel"`.

```
a=User.find_by_name 'castiel'
# 'a' will be something like #<User id:..., name: "castiel"...>
a.name #output: castiel
```

In the second example, however, the result is essentially an array of User objects.  If you call `a.name`, it will return the name of the model it holds: `User`.

```
a=User.where "name like 'c%'"
# 'a' might be something like [#<User id:..., name: "castiel"...>] 
a.name #output: User
```

Even though using `where` probably only returns you one result, it's still wrapped in an array.

Answer (score 1):

That's because when you use `where` it will return a `ActiveRecord::Relation` object and not a User object. `find_by_<blahblah>` method returns an instance of the Model.